# IsDate ArrayFormula

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

Have just noticed `isDate` does not work in `arrayformula`.

## Case

Want to filter all values if dates:

[image]

Used the formula:

`=FILTER(data,ISDATE(data))`

Expected result:

```
8/28/2018
```

Got:

```
#N/A
```

## Question

1. Why? Other checks work in `filter` (`isNumber`, `isText`, `isErr`).
2. Workarounds?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Now you can convert any formula to [arrayformula](/questions/tagged/arrayformula):

`=BYROW(A2:A12,LAMBDA(r,ISDATE(r)))`

Answer (score 13):

Please try:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(ISDATE_STRICT(A1:A11))`

[image]

The function is currently not documented.

: ISDATE_STRICT wont let date&time format, dates only

Comment: Is there documentation on this ISDATE_STRICT function?  I don't find it in the Google Sheets formula docs.  (But this solution worked for my use case.)

Answer (score 4):

1. Do not know the reason, still curious.
2. Workaround: `=FILTER(data,IFERROR(DATEVALUE(data)))` was found [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/79604/sumif-using-not-isdate)

Note: Workaround will NOT work for dates formatted as:

`dd.mm.yyyy`

You may use a duck-typed workaround:

`=FILTER(data,REGEXMATCH(MID(data,7,4),"20\d{2}"))`

Will check if formatted date has a 20XX year string inside.

Comment: It's a strange function. [3 years ago was not listed officialy](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/GJr4rE5OcQU/EtmYH6O-DwAJ). Workaround you have found is the only one I have stumbled upon.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround that could work depending on what you're trying to do as far as Arrayformula is concerned

```
=ARRAYFORUMLA(ISNUMBER(VALUE(data)))
```

- VALUE can turn the time into a number
- ISNUMBER checks if it's a number
- ISNUMBER works fine within ARRAYFORMULA

Comment: Will give TRUE for numbers. The correct formula should give TRUE for dates and FALSE for numbers