# Append check function with _Strict?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

An answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52057550/isdate-arrayformula) mentioned you can use ISDATE_STRICT in an array formula, and it worked.
I searched all over and could not find a reference to the use of _STRICT anywhere.

1. Does this apply to all "IS" check functions?
2. What exactly is it doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, unfortunately, I also don't see any articles/documentations about this one except [this](https://pastebin.com/iH353VCb).

The link above is a list of sheets formulas, we can see `_STRICT` on 3 formulas.

> ISDATE_STRICT, ISDATETIME_STRICT, ISTIME_STRICT

1. The link above does answer your first question, it does not apply to all functions `IS` functions.
2. Based on their behaviors, I guess that they strictly check if the value is treated and valid as date/time/datetime in sheets itself. Simply passing string as parameter will yield `FALSE`.

#### Testing:

[image: output]

#### Note:

- I have a hunch why `25:02:00` for `ISTIME_STRICT` is still valid for time even though it goes past `24`. Sheets automatically converted that value from the inputted value `25:02` thus suggests that what sheets treats as date/time/datetime, will always yield `TRUE` for those functions.
- To test the hypothesis above, I inputted `November 31, 2021 1:00` manually and it wasn't converted into `11/31/2021 01:00:00` automatically, it was still the same cell value because it wasn't treated as datetime variable by sheets, thus returning `FALSE`

Comment: Additional findings that you may like to add: For cell references, it seems like types are formatting-dependent too. Reformatting a date cell to a number will make it false. For a non-reference, you can pass `Date(...)` as an argument to the `ISDATE_STRICT` function.